# Why check if (lastRet < cursor) in AbstractList's iterator's remove() method?

Tags: java, listiterator

I'm reading openjdk AbstractList's iterator part. I couldn't figure out what the point is to check if (lastRet < cursor), which is always true to me.

Here, lastRet is the index of the value last returned by next(), and cursor is the index of the value to be returned by next().

The code is below:

```
public void remove() {
    if (lastRet < 0) {...} // throw exception
    checkForComodification();
    try {
        AbstractList.this.remove(lastRet);
        if (lastRet < cursor) // WHY??????????
            cursor--;
        lastRet = -1;
        expectedModCount = modCount;
    } catch (...) {
        ... // some exception
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, but without seeing the rest of the code that sets `lastRet` and `cursor`, I don't think this is answerable.

Comment: @ajb [Here's the rest of the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/AbstractList.java#AbstractList.Itr.remove%28%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code in the link provided by Spotted: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/AbstractList.java#AbstractList.Itr.remove%28%29

The code appears in the nested class `Itr`.  There's another nested class `ListItr` that extends `Itr`.  `ListItr` adds some new methods, but does not override `remove()`, which means that the code for `remove()` is the same in `Itr` and `ListItr`.

In `ListItr`, the `previous()` method sets `lastRet` and `cursor` to the same thing.  Therefore, it is not always true that `lastRet < cursor` when `remove()` is called.  It appears to always be true for a regular `Itr`, but not in a `ListItr`.